# Mac with file sharing enabled not automatically appearing under Network in Explorer on Windows 10

Tags: networking, mac, windows-explorer, macos-mojave

I have set up file sharing on both my macOS Mojave and Windows 10 computer.

So far, I can access the Windows shares from the Mac and vice versa.

The problem is that, on the Window 10 system, I can't see the Mac icon automatically listed as a network location in Windows Explorer, even though I *can* access the Mac's shares if I manually enter their UNC path in the address bar.

Is there any way to have Windows remember the Mac's address and display the Mac icon?

Answer (score 5):

Current implementation of Windows share discovery requires Web Service Discovery Daemon that is missing from Mac OS so Mac shares are not visible in Network.

WSDD, see github:
https://github.com/gershnik/wsdd-native
OR
https://github.com/christgau/wsdd
Apple uses Bonjour service:
https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/

Apple Bonjour service does not support new Microsoft Web Services Discovery protocol. Therefore Apple Shares on Windows network are not visible in Network.

To access Apple share for Windows (Samba SMB) one needs to know DNS name of the Apple computer or IP address of the Apple computer and type it into location bar like:
\\<name_or_ip_address_of_apple_computer>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I would disagree with the bot (above) here and say that this is an EXCELLENT answer. For anyone trying to network Macs and PCs and wondering why the PC can't see the Mac from Windows Explorer by default in 2023, your answer is - or at least it seems like - the only one on the internet that clarifies the situation! It's sad that this is the state of affairs 30 years into Mac and PC coexistence. Both companies should make an effort to make this easier. Networking should be painless, and it just isn't...

Comment: I would recommend using [https://github.com/gershnik/wsdd-native](https://github.com/gershnik/wsdd-native) instead since its native and install instructions for each OS.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to have Windows remember the Mac's address and display the Mac icon?

Absolutely.

Actually, the way this works is that the PC doesn't *remember* the Mac's address but the Mac continually broadcasts its presence on the network and, if everything is set up properly, the PC will see this and list the Mac in Explorer under Network.

**Most likely problem: workgroup name mismatch.**

The most likely problem here is that the Mac and PC have two different workgroup names.

If these names do not match, then the PC will not list the Mac under Network in Explorer.

1. On the Mac, go to `System Preferences`, `Network`, `Options`, `WINS`. This is most likely blank right now. Change it to "Workgroup".
2. On the PC, check the workgroup in System settings: <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd>, or <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, then scroll down and click on `System info`. Change this field to "Workgroup" also. The workgroup name can be anything you want, it just needs to be identical on your Mac and PC.

Comment: after checking setting, i can assure that the PC and the MAC workgroup names are exactly the same (WORKGROUP)

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable File Sharing on Mac OS X:

- Click on the Apple icon and then on *System Preferences*
- Click on the *Sharing* icon
- Place a check-mark next to *File Sharing*
- Click *Edit* if you wish to give the Mac an easier name for Windows
- Under *Shared Folders*, the *Public* folder is shared out by default.
  Click the `+` (plus) to share other folder(s).
  Under *Users*, edit the permissions as required.
- Click the *Options* button and ensure that all options have check-marks
- Under *Windows File Sharing* check the box next to the user name and enter a password

The specified shares should now be visible from Windows.

For more details see the article
[How to Access Mac Files from a Windows PC](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-access-mac-files-on-a-windows-pc/).

Comment: He's not asking how to set up file sharing on his Mac. That particular part of his setup is already working.